# Getting value from HTML object in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have an html object:

`<a href="https://website/" class="td-post-category" value="News" >News</a>`

Which I get from typing  `$this->get_category()`; in PHP.

My question here is if it is possible to get the value-field(News) from the HTML-object inside of PHP. Something like `$this->get_category().value` or `$this->get_category()->value`. Like we could in Javascript.

Or if you know how to "extract" variables from functions. Like if I had a variable named `$selected_category_obj_name` in the `function get_category()`, how to get this value when I have written `$this->get_category()`, how can I get the variable `$selected_category_obj_name`?

I am new to PHP, so some guiding would be very appreciated.

Comment: Question. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Is this within WordPress?

Comment: @Adam can it be Wordpress? Doesn't `get_category()` return an array or an object?

Comment: HTML doesn't have objects, it does have `<object>`, The attribute `value` is invalid for `<a>`. Looks like you're also new to HTML.

Comment: @ishegg - Not entirely sure without referring to the WordPress Codex, but if it is WP, it'll make debugging this weird use case a bit easier possibily.

Comment: Yes, this is Wordpress! With a Newspaper-theme from TagDiv on top. I just want a value I have set in the value-attribute in the HTML-object. So I can use that for an if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$html = '<a href="https://website/" class="td-post-category" value="News" >News</a>';
preg_match("/value=\"(.+)\"/i", $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // News
```

The pattern simply looks for anything more than once in between `value="` and `"`, returning the results into the `$matches` array..

Or [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and traverse the DOM to get to the attribute of the element:

```
$html = '<a href="https://website/" class="td-post-category" value="News" >News</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
var_dump($doc->getElementsByTagName("a")->item(0)->getAttribute("value")); // News
```

[Demos](https://3v4l.org/dgdQT)